# What are the Christmas easter eggs for Minecraft 1.7.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I went to play some Minecraft and noticed my vanilla chests are looking quite festive today:

[image]

The single chests are red, double chests green.

I ran around for a bit but didn't notice any other differences. What other changes can I expect for Christmas?

Comment: I think the chests get the makeover every year but not certain. AFAIK it's the only change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only changes that Mojang implemented this year was the changing of the texture for the chests. They did the exact same thing last year as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you name a sheep egg jeb_ OR use a nametag and name the sheep jeb_ it makes the sheep rainbow!

Comment: This is an easter egg, but it is not a Christmas easter egg, seeing that it can happen year round.

Comment: lol, its funny, like the Dinnerbone upsidedown trick

Comment: "I'm always upside down" Dinnerbone