# What are the Minecraft Easter eggs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147628/what-are-the-christmas-easter-eggs-for-minecraft-1-7-4/147870#147870) and I didn't realize that Minecraft had some Easter eggs in it. Besides the Christmas chest Easter egg, and the sheep Easter egg, what else is there?

Comment: I don't know why this was put on hold, it is a viable question, and something I would like to know too.

Comment: I added the details for the two easter eggs you briefly touched in the question as answers. This will help if someone comes across your question and wonders what existing easter eggs you are referring to.

Comment: That is not really necessary in the answers @IQAndreas.

Comment: After seeing several answers here, I have come to the conclusion that this is far too broad.  There are too many answers that each list a different item, making this a list type question, where voting is done on popularity, not helpfulness.

Comment: There has already been a discussion on Meta about this and it was deemed to be acceptable. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/what-defines-a-question-as-being-too-broad-when-asking-about-easter-eggs

Comment: @shanodin One or two vote answers don't really do much to really decide consensus.

Comment: I voted to close this *specifically* due to it's history of fragmented, incomplete, and low-quality answers.  No one has taken the time or effort to compile a single, complete, definitive answer (if such is even possible), and keep it up to date.  Unless that effort will be made, this question should be closed, and kept that way.

Comment: @Frank So what do you define shanodin's answer as?

Comment: Incomplete.  What defines an, "Easter egg"?  The term is too vague to have decent meaning.  Her answer lists *some* of them, but it is by no means complete.

Comment: I don't see why this is too broad. We have loads of questions like 'what are all the x in y' (gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+are+all+the) and I don't see what the difference of this one is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Halloween - on October 31st, some mobs will have pumpkins on their heads, and may drop a pumpkin if killed.
- Christmas - between 24th - 26th December, chests are reskinned to look like presents

  [image: Christmas Chests]
- Mobs - naming a sheep or a sheep spawn egg 'jeb_' will result in rainbow sheep (a sheep which cycles through the colours)

  [image: jeb_ sheep]
- Mobs - naming any mob/mob spawn egg 'Dinnerbone' or 'Grumm' will make it render upside-down

  [image: Dinnerbone cow][image: Grumm cow]
- April Fools - Mojang often have special jokes for 1st April, e.g Minecraft 2.0 from Apr 2013
- Text for the updates/bugfix lists often includes 'Removed Herobrine' as a reference to an urban legend about the game

  [image: Removed Herobrine]
- If you ever kill Notch himself, he drops an apple
- Crash logs occassionally include tongue-in-cheek statements such as 'Don't do that again'
  [image: Crash text]
- On the game's main menu, there is a 0.01% chance that it will say Minceraft instead of Minecraft
- If the file with the list of splash text lines (the yellow text on the main menu) is deleted, it will display as 'missingno' which is a reference to the infamous glitch in the early Pokémon games.

Sources - many, many hours of Minecraft (and [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Easter_eggs))

Comment: I wonder how many people have gotten Minceraft but never noticed it?

Comment: 'If you ever kill Notch himself, he drops an apple' When and how would this ever happen?

Comment: @zibbobz Notch occasionally participates in charity events such as the Mindcrack Livestream. Dinnerbone has been in a few of their Ultra Hardcore series' too.

Comment: @Zibbobz If Notch (using his eponymous Minecraft account) joins a Minecraft server that you're on.

Comment: killing notch doesn't drop an apple anymore. I've watched him die in a video before, no apple.

Answer (score 8):

Also Deadmau5 has his trademark ears in game. They are visible to everyone and in the vinilla client. [image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answer...

The text used in the enchantment table is actually from Doom/Commander Keen and is known as the Galactic Alphabet. You actually can transliterate the text to English (there are many more Easter eggs in that alone)*

The texture for zombie pigmen, in the actual texture file, contains a call out to the original artist.

Making your first cake gets you the achievement "The Cake is a Lie" and popular meme in reference to Portal by Valve.

Getting an achievement displays "Achievement Get" which is a reference to Super Mario Sunshine for the Nintendo GameCube.

While fishing you will occasionally pull up leather boots, which is a reference to Zelda game.

*After they changed the enchantment system to include tool-tips, I do not know if the text is still translatable.

Comment: "Achievement Get" is a reference to Super Mario Sunshine for the Nintendo GameCube. In that game, "Shine Get!" is shown when the player collects a shine sprite. See the [minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Achievements) for more references.

Comment: @NickB. Thank you, I blanked when I was listing these and I just couldn't remember that one.

Comment: @Texenox I thought that sounded funny in my head when I wrote it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Name an animal Dinnerbone an it will turn upside down

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, every year on Christmas, the textures of single and double chests will change to look like wrapped Christmas presents:

[image: Single and double chests looking like Christmas presents]

*Image by [**@gnovice**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/15/gnovice) ([source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147628/what-are-the-christmas-easter-eggs-for-minecraft-1-7-4))*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, if you use a [nametag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nametag) to rename a sheep to `jeb_` (the underscore is required) the sheep will constantly shift hue (also known as "rainbow sheep" or "disco sheep").

The result (and small tutorial) is shown in the following video:

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you go into the languages, you have there three joke ones:  Pirate Speak, Lolcat, and ɥsᴉlƃuƎ (ʞ∩).

Answer (score -2):

When you do name a sheep jeb_ when you sheer it the wool will be the color of the original sheep

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer